# Calling A URL Variable Inside Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to load a set of predetermined URLs into an iframe in a particular order with a particular time for each slide.

One of the slides (Events.php) points to a URL that displays random content each time it refreshes. I'm trying to append the Events.php URL with a random number to force it to reload each time it is loaded into the iframe.

```
   <script>

var frames = Array(
                   getRandomUrl(), 5
                   );

var myUniqueTime = getUniqueTime;

/* Now every time you call getRandomUrl you should get back a unique url. */
function getRandomUrl()
{
    return "http://www.example.com/Events.php?=" + myUniqueTime;
}

function ChangeSrc()
{
  if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
  document.getElementById('myiframe').src = frames[i++];
  return setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}    

/* We'll make a closure here that will make sure you don't get duplicates! */
function getUniqueTime(startingFrom)
{
    startingFrom = startingFrom || (new Date().getTime());
    return function()
    {
        return startingFrom++;
    }
}

var i = 0, len = frames.length;
window.onload = ChangeSrc;


</script>
```

Any help or just a point in the right direction would be much appreciated! :)

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Thanks for the replys, don't think my original question was clear so I've reworded it above...

Comment: Answered here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427925/appending-different-random-number-to-url-in-javascript-array-on-each-loop/28428276#28428276
Thanks for everyone's input, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript looping and closures are confusing. Rather just use a function:

```
<script>

var frames = Array(getRandomUrl(), getRandomUrl(), getRandomUrl() );
alert(frames); //remove this - just shows you that it works
var i = 0, len = frames.length;
window.onload = ChangeSrc;

function getRandomUrl()
{
    return "http://www.example.com/Events.php?=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
}

function ChangeSrc()
{
  if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
  document.getElementById('myiframe').src = frames[i++];
  setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}    

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Much appreciated, however, it doesn't seem to work... The iFrame isn't loading anything into it.

If I add a couple of other slides they appear but the getRandomUrl isn't displaying the Events.php page

Comment: I've got the Event.php loading into the iframe now, I just needed to put a time for the frame in the array. Only thing now is the random number append to the end of the URL (which is meant to force a reload of the page to generate a new random event) is the same numbers each time it loops. I need the "/Events.php?=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999) to generate a new random string each time it is displayed. Is that possible?

Comment: If I run this code in jsfiddle.net it gives me new URLs every time, how are you calling it?

var frames = Array(getRandomUrl(), getRandomUrl(),  getRandomUrl() );
alert(frames);
function getRandomUrl()
{
    return "http://www.example.com/Events.php?=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
}

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure how you are trying to do this, but lets try to amend this code a bit and see if we can make it work.

First, a couple of changes to your variable declaration. From what I gather, you want to complete a URL with a 'value' (which is just a string) for an event, and you want to save a 'timeout time' (which is a number of milliseconds) as well. Now, in order to do this it is better to create an `array` of `object`s. In php, this would be a numeric array with nested associative arrays (aka `array(array("a"=>"b"), array("c"=>"d"));`). In Javascript you use `new Array()` or `[]` to start an array, not php's `array()` 'function'. Similarly, Javascript will create an `object` (or associative array in php parlance) if you call either `new Object();` or use `{}`.

```
/* Update 3: Added this function here to get a random-isch number */
function getUniqueTime(startingFrom){
    startingFrom = startingFrom || new Date().getTime();
    return function(){
        return startingFrom++;
    }
}
var myUniqueTime = getUniqueTime();

/* Update 3: Added an easy way to get unique URLs and not confuse it with timings. */
var frames = [
    {event: 'http://url.tld/?data=' + myUniqueTime(), timeout: 5000},
    {event: 'http://url.tld/?data=' + myUniqueTime(), timeout: 10000},
    {event: 'http://url.tld/?data=' + myUniqueTime(), timeout: 5000}
];
```

Now all we need to do it modify your function a bit. Get a random element from your frames array, and then ask that element to return the value you saved in the key 'event' and the one in the key 'timeout'.

```
/* Start with i negative so at the first increment it will become 0 and not 1. */
var i = -1;
function ChangeSrc(){
    /* SCheck if i+1 is bigger than frames.length, if so go to 0, otherwise increment. */
    i = i + 1 >= frames.length ? 0 : i + 1;
    var myevent = frames[i];
    console.log(myevent.event)
    setTimeout(ChangeSrc, myevent.timeout);
}

window.onload = ChangeSrc;
```

One last thing is that the `setTimeout` function takes variables that represent functions, so you just pass it ChangeSrc itself without calling it (so no `()`). And it takes milliseconds as a value, so its best to just declare those in the variables immediatly.

### Update

I am still not 100% sure of what you are doing but if you want the string to be different every time, you could just use new Date().getTime() instead of randomising. Its exactly the same as the php strtotime("now")` function, and the string is guaranteed to be different every time you call it. But maybe a closure is useful here, so maybe try this:

```
/* We'll make a closure here that will make sure you don't get duplicates! */
function getUniqueTime(startingFrom){
    startingFrom = startingFrom || new Date.getTime();
    return function(){
        return startingFrom++;
    }
}

var myUniqueTime = getUniqueTime();

/* Now every time you call getRandomUrl you should get back a unique url. */
function getRandomUrl(){
    return "http://www.example.com/Events.php?=" + myUniqueTime();
}
```

Did that help?

#### Updated original answer

I have added the random number generator in the original answer. I have tried to make this work with the code already there but it's to difficult compared to how easely it can be done with my original answer. I've added a snippet and updated the code to run more in line with what you intended.

```js
function getUniqueTime(startingFrom){
    startingFrom = startingFrom || new Date().getTime();
    return function(){
        return startingFrom++;
    }
}
var myUniqueTime = getUniqueTime();
var i = -1;

var frames = [
    {event: 'http://url.tld/?data=' + myUniqueTime(), timeout: 5000},
    {event: 'http://url.tld/?data=' + myUniqueTime(), timeout: 10000},
    {event: 'http://url.tld/?data=' + myUniqueTime(), timeout: 5000}
];

function ChangeSrc(){
    i = i + 1 >= frames.length ? 0 : i + 1;
    var myevent = frames[i];
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = document.getElementById("console").innerHTML + "<br />" + myevent.event + " (waiting " + myevent.timeout + "s)";
    setTimeout(ChangeSrc, myevent.timeout);
}
window.onload = ChangeSrc;
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, don't think my original question was clear so I've reworded it above...

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.
I've tried the new code but i'm not getting anything loading into the iframe now. I've updated the code above to reflect what I have now...

Comment: Okay I think its time to get serious about debugging. Assign your URL top a variable, `console.log` it before returning the variable itself and then manually go to the page to see what is going wrong, as the code should generate a random number and the bug is not going to be in the Javascript. I'm thinking @RickHitchcock has a good lead on the possible mistake there might be in php...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: myUniqueTime is not a function
getRandomUrl
(anonymous function)

Comment: ...function getUniqueTime(startingfrom){... should be (startingFrom) CaPiTaL F. Still generating Events.php?=undefined as the URL variable though

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake or two. Make sure al variables are the same (aka `startingFrom` and not `startingfrom `) and add a `return` within tne enclosed function to return the number. Now try again. Sorry! I updated my psot. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: myUniqueTime is not a function
getRandomUrl
(anonymous function)
And a blank iframe with no URL

Comment: You have mis ordered things. Try to do all your function calls at the end. Heres what I changed when I copied the code you currently have in your post: I moved var `frames`, `i`, `len` and `window.onload` to the _end_ of your code. Then I also added a `()` to the new Date constructor (`new Date().getTime();`). I **also** added a `return;` statement to your `if` statement in `ChangeSrc`since otherwise it would start looping endlessly. When you reset i to 0, you need to actually end the function there as the timeout will call the function automatically.

Comment: Actually the more I look into this the more ridiculous it gets. Please see my original answer which will separate the timeouts from the links you want to link to. You can still use random number appending in those, but the fact that index `0` is your link and index `1` is a timeout time, and then it switches again... Its overcomplicated for no reason. Nest objects in your array and make clear and readable code is the best solution, so please try to use/modify my original answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Still not working though! I've reordered and updated the code above but getting Event.php?=undefined as the generated URL... I also took the () off the end of the Event.php?=" + muUniqueTime(); as it was giving me a "myUniqueTime Is Not A Function" error

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I have updated the original to show how it works with the knowledge of what you want to accomplish. I have also added a snippet.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but still cant figure it. Off for a while now but I'll try again later

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure this out for me but the code snippet doesn't work. I run the sippet and I get........... http://url.tld/?data=0001 (waiting 5000s), http://url.tld/?data=0002 (waiting 5000s), http://url.tld/?data=0003 (waiting 5000s).......... http://url.tld/?data=0001 (waiting 5000s), http://url.tld/?data=0002 (waiting 5000s), http://url.tld/?data=0003 (waiting 5000s).......... http://url.tld/?data=0001 (waiting 5000s), http://url.tld/?data=0002 (waiting 5000s), http://url.tld/?data=0003 (waiting 5000s).............. Same three URLs repeated......

Comment: Thats because those are in the array... The snippet is a proof of concept, showing that it creates an array of urls and then prints, waits, prints... Wrince and repeat. It shows that it works. I cant do iframes here and i have no urls to load in them. Please try to understand the code as i cannot explain it any more than i did. Good luck.

Comment: Appologies for the confusion, I mustn't have made myself clear from the start but I needed the /Events.php to refresh EVERY time giving me a new content, not just loop through the same ones. I'm sure I'll get it sorted eventually but thanks for your time, appreciated.

Comment: In that case you don't need a range at all! Just remove the array and variables there and call the get UniqueUrl every time ChangeSrc() is called and you're done. (aka `function ChangeSrc(){ var url = getUniqueUrl(); document.getElementById("iframe").src = url; setTimeout(ChangeSrc,5000);};`)... It makes it a lot easier. You just made it harder with the predefined list!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for query strings is:

```
?field1=value1[&field2=value2...]
```

You have omitted `field1` and are using:

```
?=value1
```

... where `value1` is a random number.

This may not be enough to indicate to designate this as a new URL.

Try something like this:

```
return "http://www.example.com/Events.php?rnd=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
```