# Appending Different Random Number To URL In Javascript Array On Each Loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying (without much success) to create an array which contains slides being loaded into an iframe. One of these frames *(/Events.php)* uses PHP to query a WordPress database and show 1 post chosen at random. This slide needs to show a **different** random post **every time** the array loops through.

My code at them moment is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var frames = Array(
    'http://www.example.com/Slide01.php', 5,
    'http://www.example.com/Slide02.php', 5,
    getRandomUrl(), 5,
    'http://www.example.com/Slide04.php', 5
    );

var i = 0, len = frames.length;

function getRandomUrl()
{
    return "http://www.example.com/Events.php?=" + (new Date().getTime());
}

function ChangeSrc()
{
  if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
  document.getElementById('myiframe').src = frames[i++];
  setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}
window.onload = ChangeSrc;
</script>
```

The only trouble is everytime */Events.php* is shown it has the same number appended to it so therefore shows the same post in each loop.

I need to append a different number to the */Events.php* slide on each loop so it generates different content each time.

I'm starting to think I'm approaching this in totally the wrong way so any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Cheers,
Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are only calling `getRandomUrl()` once which is when you defined your array, this means the value will always be the same as its only returned once.

One solution would be to store the function itself in your array like so:

```
var frames = Array(
    'http://www.example.com/Slide01.php', 5,
    'http://www.example.com/Slide02.php', 5,
    getRandomUrl, 5,
    'http://www.example.com/Slide04.php', 5
    );
```

And then call it in `ChangeSrc()` if its a function

```
function ChangeSrc()
{
  if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
    var frame = frames[i++],
        isFnc = typeof(frame) == "function";
    if(isFnc){
        frame = frame();
    }
    document.getElementById('myiframe').src = frame;
    setTimeout(function(){
        ChangeSrc()
    }, frames[i++]*1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/redgg6pq/

Comment: That worked a treat! Top man! Thank you very much indeed! :) Saved me hours (and hours) of more head scratching!

Answer (score 0):

A tip would be that you are only calling 'getRandomUrl' once, hence why it's always the same image. You want to call it each time you are in the loop.

I would suggest removing it from the static array, and calling it in the loop - does that make sense? :)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Not sure what you mean (JS Isn't my strongest point!) Do you mean in my Wordpress loop actually on the /Events.php page?